# convert SQL to HQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql

I want to retrieve some information from Oracle database.

The following query provides me with the required result:

```
select pl.* 
from PEOPLE pl 
    INNER JOIN ANIMALS c on pl.ID = c.PEOPLE_FK 
where c.ID=(select HEALTH_RES.ANIMALS_FK 
            FROM HEALTH_RES 
            WHERE HEALTH_RES='1234');
```

Explanation: each person may have many animals, each animal has only one health result. I want to find owner (all information about him) of animal by `id` of health result.

Now I have Entities mapped in java, and I want to use a `HQL` query to obtain such information, how would such query look in HQL?

I have tried this:

```
 select pl from PeopleEntity as pl inner join pl.animals as c where c.Id=(select HealthResEntity.animals_FK FROM HealthResEntity WHERE HealthResEntity.id=:idParam)
```

But it seem to not work, what is wrong with this query?

EDIT: I am getting null pointer exception when calling method that converts Entity object to domain object which means no data was retrieved

Comment: Try to change c.Id = ,  with c.Id in

Comment: What does it mean *"it seem not to work"*? What's error?

Comment: null pointer exception when calling method that converts Entity object to domain object wchih means no data was retrived